# Adding WPF Desktop Projects Application(with multiple modules) to build InstallShield Setup

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, installshield

I have a WPF desktop project with several modules like bellow image. They are much like MVC pattern, means one module depends on another. I want to build setup using InstallShield. If someone please help me?

I followed the tutorial bellow, but after install, it doesn't work at all !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mgu0y34HsVM

Please note that I am using VS 2013.[image: This is my Solution Explorer view]

Thanks!

Comment: In what way does it fail? What error or behavior are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

try to add files manually , in application files tab  . press "Add files" go to your startup project if you have multiple project in your solution . then go to debug folder , Add your executable file . "an exe file " then continue deploying